# CListCTrl - How to Align Text from specify Column?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to align the header text to center while body data will align to left.

This's my illustrations:

In the `OnInitDialog` event, I added the column as follows:

```
mylistCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, CTRLrect, &m_cTab, IDC_ctrlist);
mylistCtrl.InsertColumn(1, L"Column1", LVCFMT_LEFT, 50);
```

then I try accessing `CHeaderCtrl` like this:

```
m_checkHeadCtrl = mylistCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl(); 
if (m_checkHeadCtrl)
{
    m_checkHeadCtrl->ModifyStyle(1, HDS_HOTTRACK); //<--not sure this option
    HDITEM hdi = { 0 };

    m_checkHeadCtrl->GetItem(1, &hdi);
    hdi.mask = HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT;
    hdi.fmt |= HDF_CENTER;
    m_checkHeadCtrl->SetItem(1, &hdi);
}
```

However this is not working?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it in this way:

```
HDITEM hdi{ 0 };
hdi.mask = HDI_TEXT | HDI_FORMAT;
pHeader->GetItem(1, &hdi)
hdi.fmt |= HDF_CENTER;
pHeader->SetItem(1, &hdi);

pHeader->ModifyStyle(0, HDS_HOTTRACK); // optional
```

Of course, you have to assure that you have your text as valid inside your header control.

Comment: Hi @flaviu2, I changed as your code but the this column now blank(text invisible) . am i wrong when setting `hdi.mask and hdi.fmt`?

Comment: As I cannot see the entire code, I can't say if it is wrong or not, but you can also check this model: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/866/using-the-header-control

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be:

```cpp
HDITEM hdi{ HDI_FORMAT };
hdi.fmt = HDF_CENTER;
pHeader->SetItem(1, &hdi);
```

By setting `HDI_TEXT |` mask you also asking for header item's text, but not provide a buffer for it.
Then, when you `m_checkHeadCtrl->SetItem(1, &hdi);` you, in fact, setting an empty text to the header, and therefore you see it blank.

Comment: Hi @Jovibor, I tried but all are align centered. I will try to investigate this further.